# Disable import of JUnit 3 classes

Tags: eclipse, configuration, junit4, junit3

I want to develop JUnit 4 tests only. When writing Unit Tests, Eclipse often imports classes from `junit.framework`, which is JUnit 3.

This has lead to various problems, e.g. when expecting an Exception, it simply doesn't catch it if it's in the wrong package like this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import junit.framework.ComparisonFailure;
[...]
try 
{
     assertEquals(0, 1);
}
catch(ComparisonFailure cfe)
{
}
```

Strange enough, if I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on `ComparisonFailure`, it says

> Source not found
>
> The JAR of this class belongs to container 'JUnit 4' [...]

Perhaps helpful environment information:

- I don't have JUnit 3 in my build path.
- Eclipse Luna 4.4.1

**How can I stop Eclipse from importing JUnit 3 classes?**

I have read [Why is Eclipse using JUnit 3 when I have junit-4.3.1.jar in my build path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/965454/4136325), but it's rather old and probably does not apply to Luna any more. Also, my problem is not in *running* the test, it's in *implementing* the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, JUnit 4 depends on some of the classes that were developed originally within JUnit 3 or reside in packages `junit.*`. One of such class is `ComparisonFailure`. If you look at latest JUnit 4.12 you will see that these packages are still there.

However, sources jar do contain java files for these classes. Perhaps your library that contains JUnit (do you use Eclipse JUnit library?) lacks source files for these? Where does your dependency (junit.jar) come from?

Comment: You mean https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/junit/framework/ComparisonFailure.java versus https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/ComparisonFailure.java. That might indeed be the reason. Why do they do such things?

Comment: Probably for backward comaptibility. You can use access rules to make junit.* packages discouraged (will generate warnings) or forbidden (will not show up in content assist) through Project preferences->Java Build Path->Libraries (tab)->your_junit*.jar->Access rules.

Answer (score 7):

Another workaround for Eclipse's users is the following solution:
Windows -> Preferrences -> Java -> Appearance -> Type filters 
and add junit.framework.* to the exclusion list.

Comment: Thanks! This  made test coding easier.

Answer (score 0):

Which dependencies has your plugin ? Junit 3.X or 4.X ?

You could search your workspace for any references in junit 3 and change/remove them.

Comment: Which plugin? I am referencing dom4j-1.6.1.jar which uses JUnit 3. And I have installed findbugs-3.0.0.jar (not in the build path) which uses JUnit 3. Could that really be the problem, a library which is referencing JUnit?